# What is required to map local directory to pseudo URL using Vagrant?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, hosts

I'm on a mac, and have Virtual Box and Vagrant set up properly, using the [avenuefactory/lamp](https://vagrantcloud.com/avenuefactory/boxes/lamp) box. I'm new to Vagrant, so I'm trying to see what is required to map `local.example.com` to a code base located at `~/code/example/public` on my host machine. I've tried using the `config.vm.network` in my Vagrantfile to point to a specific IP, but not sure how to edit Vagrant's equivalent of a vhosts file.

Again, I'm new to this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand
Do you try to access to your code from virtual host?
In this case Looks like you have to do following:

```
config.vm.syncedfolder "~/code/example/public", "/var/www/html"
```

if you need to have access to your virtual host by name, then 
you need to add to `/etc/hosts` in host mashine something like:

```
192.168.10.10 local.example.com
```

Comment: I think the question is very straightforward and the answer to this question is very hard to find.  OP is asking "How do I map local.example.com to ~/code/example/public in vagrant?    
    
The problem with your answer is it that it is not clear how config.vm.syncedfolder directive maps to local.example.com.  Surely, something must tell vagrant that "local.example.com" maps specifically to  ""~/code/example/public".  In addition, I do not have an "html" directory in "/var/www".  I guess what I am saying is that it is not clear how your answer solves the problem.